# How can I set the order of the actions in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I saw that in a Kendo Grid if you modify and add some rows the order of the requests is: Create and after that Update. It is possible to change this order and to call the Update action first and after that the Create action?

Thank you in advance,
Vlad Cristea

Answer (score 0):

Not possible out of the box. You either have to [modify the source code](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.data.js#L2645-L2647_) or implement a custom kendo.data.DataSource transport - set transport.update and [transport.create](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.create) as functions.

Comment: I have tried the second option but still the same order. I would not like to change the source code.

Comment: You have to write some code. I forgot to mention that.

1. When transport.create is called - cache the data
2. When transport.update is called - send the updated data and then the cached data from transport.create